# how to update new password in maintenance plan

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have changed the SQL account password but my all backups have failed. How do I update the new password manager connection in the maintenance plan from the backup?

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to SSMS --> Management-->Maintenance plans

Click on you Maint Tasks -->Right Click and select Modify

On this page you find Manage Connections

Check the Manage connections there you find options to change the credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to SSMS --> Management-->Maintenance plans[image]

[image]